# Storing Express data in global variable through view

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a data object "bootstrappedUser" being passed into the view through a route.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs',{
      bootstrappedUser: req.user,
      page: 'rest'
    });
});
```

I'd like to store the "bootstrappedUser" JSON object into a global variable and use that variable to keep persistent login. Currently the window.bootstrappedUserObject is being accessed when bootstrappedUser is defined but it is not being set to anything.

```
 <% if (bootstrappedUser!= undefined) { %>
  <script>
  window.bootstrappedUserObject = <% bootstrappedUser %>                
</script>
<% } %>
```

I am receiving the following source code on login

```
<script>
window.bootstrappedUserObject =                                        
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>`:

```
 <% if (bootstrappedUser!= undefined) { %>
  <script>
  window.bootstrappedUserObject = <%= bootstrappedUser %>                
</script>
<% } %>
```

`<% %>` just evaluates JavaScript whereas `<%= %>` interpolates the result of an expression into your template.